# Discord.JS member.voice is undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

there is a problem with Discord.JS. On voiceStateUpdate event when getting the voice field in member it is undefined

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldMember, newMember: GuildMember) => {
  console.log(newMember.voice) // == undefined
})
```

Comment: can you log the data and check if oldMember/newMember has any data?

Comment: expecting code to be something similar to here https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#client

Comment: oldMember and newMember has data

Comment: It turns out that newMember and oldMember are VoiceState and not GuildMember

Comment: thats' right. it should have these fields only: **channel_id, user_id, session_id, deaf, mute, self_deaf, self_mute, suppress**. https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/voice

Comment: @Abhilash Because it's a Discord.js [`VoiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState), there are different properties for those things: `channelID`, `id`, `sessionID`, `serverDeaf`, `serverMute`, `selfDeaf`, and `selfMute` (Discord.js does not store `suppress`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using discord.js v12, it isn't member, it is a voiceState https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState